# imputation of missing values

Tags: r, statistical-significance, missing-data

I have a data looks like this ( I used log2 to normalise my data) 
zeros means missing values. is there a way to impute it which does not interrupt statistical test ?

```
df<- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Subject = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L), 
    Value = c(29.89577946, 29.51885854, 29.77429604, 33.20695108, 
    32.09027292, 31.90909894, 30.88358173, 30.67547731, 30.82494595, 
    31.70128247, 31.57217504, 31.61359752, 30.51371055, 30.42241945, 
    30.44913954, 26.90850496, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.94047335, 29.27188604, 
    29.78511206, 28.18475423, 27.54266717, 26.99873401, 29.26941344, 
    28.50457189, 28.78050443, 31.39038527, 31.19237052, 30.74053275, 
    28.68618888, 28.42109545, 28.58222544, 28.99337177, 29.31797, 
    28.4541501, 28.18475423, 27.54266717, 26.99873401, 28.07576794, 
    28.96344894, 28.48358437, 27.02527663, 27.1308483, 26.96091103, 
    27.04019758, 27.51900858, 28.14559621, 26.83569136, 26.90724462, 
    26.82675, 0, 0, 0, 27.62449786, 26.82335228, 26.66925534, 
    0, 25.81254792, 26.61666776, 26.12545858, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    28.84580419, 29.11003424, 29.24723895, 28.72919768, 29.70673437, 
    29.31274377, 30.73133587, 30.44805655, 30.61561583, 27.06896964, 
    27.04249553, 27.15990629, 31.54738209, 31.51643714, 31.8055509, 
    31.291867, 31.89146186, 31.65812735)), .Names = c("Group", 
"Subject", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-87L))
```

Comment: There's a saying, just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. I would be cautious about statistical imputation. I've used it, and suggested it in the past, but this is not a good situation where statistical imputation will benefit you. The previous post I've provided an answer to you is not affected by missing data. If you're not coming from a strong statistical background, I suggest not pursuing data imputation.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis ...why? Your comment lacks any arguments for it.

Comment: @Tim, from a previous thread, Nik discusses some details on the design of the data, and from there it does not seem that data could be MAR/MCAR and hence, data imputation would not benefit him.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis if so, maybe you want to extend the comment into an answer?

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis the data is not MAR or MCAR, but I see that people do the imputation on different types of data, for example this paper (i selected because it is freely available and you can read it http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jproteome.5b00981

Comment: @NikBernou, at the end of the day it's your data, analysis and results. And if you have to present it to a room full of people with questions, just be ready to provide an answer for your methodology of choice.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis you are right! I do have doubt and that is why I made a question in the first place. I do appreciate all your valuable help and comments , really

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not MCAR or MAR, I do not recommend statistical imputation. From your previous posts, your data does not look like it is MAR/MCAR and hence, imputation is NOT appropriate.

Here's a referrence on missing data that might be at your level: 
https://liberalarts.utexas.edu/prc/_files/cs/Missing-Data.pdf

Comment: can you please define also MCAR and MAR and why not do imputation outside of them? so that I accept your answer

Comment: @NikBernou: As a starting point you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Types_of_missing_data.